# Why a projection is singular and an identity mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I got this question on one of my linear algebra assignments. I don't understand how to prove any of the points asked, theoretically it seems pretty trivial it doesn't even need a proof.

Let E be a linear operator on R^n
for which $E^2 = E$. (Such an operator is called a projection.) Let U be the image of E, and
let W be the kernel of E. Prove:

- If $u ∈ U$, then $E(u) = u$, i.e., E is the identity mapping on U.
- If $E \not= I$, then E is singular, i.e., $E(v) = 0$ for some $v  \not= 0$.
- $R^n = U ⊕ W$

Comment: If you cannot prove them maybe they are not that trivial! For the first point, have you tried to fix $u \in U$? What can you say about him?

Comment: First try proving $v\in\operatorname{Im}(E)\iff v=Ev$ What are the only possible eigenvalues?

Comment: We haven't covered eigenvalues yet so I can't use them in the proof.
To @blamethelag what do you mean by fixing ∈?

Comment: Take $u \in U$, there exists $v \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $u = Ev$. Then $E(u)=$...